# If statement error with variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, if-statement

I have had this problem for a while and finally i narrowed it down to what it is (I think).
I am trying to put a limit on a income and the limit is $storagecap each $warehouse is = to 500 $storagecap. Before i show you the code I will tell you my problem.
It shows what your limit is example at the moment i own 2 $warehouse's and it says my limit is 1000 but it stops my income at 499 which i set equal to 0 warehouses so it shows 499/1000. Cron_turn adds your income to your account.

I don't know why it stops at 499 when it knows $storagecap is 1000.

***storagecap.php***

```
<?php

$warehouse = $building['warehouse'];

if ($warehouse == 1) {
$storagecap = 500;
}elseif($warehouse == 2) {
$storagecap = 1000;
}elseif($warehouse == 3) {
$storagecap = 1500;
}elseif($warehouse == 4) {
$storagecap = 2000;
}elseif($warehouse == 5) {
$storagecap = 2500;
}elseif($warehouse == 6) {
$storagecap = 3000;
}elseif($warehouse == 7) {
$storagecap = 3500;
}elseif($warehouse == 8) {
$storagecap = 4000;
}elseif($warehouse == 9) {
$storagecap = 4500;
}elseif($warehouse == 10) {
$storagecap = 5000;
}elseif($warehouse == 11) {
$storagecap = 5500;
}elseif($warehouse == 12) {
$storagecap = 6000;
}elseif($warehouse == 13) {
$storagecap = 6500;
}elseif($warehouse == 14) {
$storagecap = 7000;
}elseif($warehouse == 15) {
$storagecap = 7500;
}elseif($warehouse == 16) {
$storagecap = 8000;
}elseif($warehouse == 17) {
$storagecap = 8500;
}elseif($warehouse == 18) {
$storagecap = 9000;
}elseif($warehouse == 19) {
$storagecap = 9500;
}elseif($warehouse == 20) {
$storagecap = 10000;
}elseif($warehouse == 0) {
$storagecap = 499;
}else{
$storagecap = 10;
}
?>
```

***cron_turn.php***

```
<?php 
include("functions.php");
connect();
include("safe.php");
include("storagecap.php");
$get_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `stats`") or die(mysql_error());

while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_users)) {
  //Get
  $gold = $user["gold"];
  $food = $user["food"];
  $energy = $user["energy"];

  //Increment
  $gold += $user["income"];
  $food += $user["farming"];
  $energy += 5;

  //Verify and correct
  if ($energy > 100) {
     $energy = 100;
  };

  if ($gold > $storagecap) {
     $gold = $storagecap;
  };

  if ($food > $storagecap) {
     $food = $storagecap;
  };

  //Submit
  $update = mysql_query("UPDATE `stats` SET
                    `gold`= '".$gold."',
                    `food`= '".$food."',
                    `energy`= '".$energy."' WHERE `id`='".$user['id']."'") or     die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: Someone has apparently never heard of [`switch`](http://php.net/switch)...

Comment: `$storagecap = 500 * $warehouse` with some border conditions?

Comment: Where is `$building['warehouse']` set?

Comment: @Kolink Someone has apparently never heard of *multiplication*...

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well, I would have used that, but then there's that weird case with `0` and the final `else`. I don't know enough about what's going on there to be certain.

Comment: $building is set in safe.php it selects the table and inside the table  is 'warehouse'

Comment: switch or even better just an array

Answer (score 0):

You are including the storagecap.php file prior to setting the assigning a value to `$building['warehouse']`.  Since you are comparing null to an int in the if statement the 0 rings true.  move the include down past a point where you have a value for `$building['warehouse']`

Comment: this makes the capacity = 499 which means 0 warehouses as well as gold and food

Answer (score 0):

It's not the normal way of defining storages. I see you are building a game. Let's guess you have buildings which makes you income (gold, etc) and buildings for capacite (storage). They both should be saved in `buildings` table so each level has defined income i.e. 1st level gold_buildings => 100 gold/h; 1st level storage => 500 capacity (income column).

Then, each user, should have its own building levels in a separate table, i.e. user_buildings:

```
user_id | building_id | level
```

Most of the games, each user is developing this buildings on some platform (planet, kingdom, depends on the idea), let's say in your case it's just a "platform"

table `platforms`

```
id | user_id | income_gold | income_food | energy | capacity_gold | capacity_food | gold | food |
```

so, everytime your user access the relevant menu with the incomes, your are updating the `platform` table, depending on the user_buildings levels, you are building how many the income is, and the capacity aswell.

When the cron turns, it should take the values from that table, and compare.

Let's say you have 100 gold income, 350 on your platform, and 500 capacity:

```
UPDATE platform SET gold = IF((gold+gold_income)>capacity, `capacity`, gold+gold_income);
```

The IF condition (didn't test it to be honest) should check whether the income plus the current gold is exceeding the limit, so if true, it makes the gold column equals the capacity (limit), if it doesn't, it adds the income to the current gold.

However, some of the games are adding the resource, no matter it's exceeding the limit, and later another cron checks for platforms with exceeded limit, and updates down to the limit.

P.S.: The crone which gives resources, I think, does not need WHERE clause about user_id, since it should be giving income to everyone (or if not, you should just exclude, i.e. banned accounts)

Comment: this is a very good idea I will try and implement it in but for now i would just like to fix my problem as this looks a bit confusing

Comment: you are not recieving the warehouse level from your fetch, or at least not in $warehouse variable, thus leads to your `else` statement or evaluates to 0.

Comment: i kind of get that i just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Where do you have the storage level, if it's in the given query then you need $storage = $user['storage'];